# Number of triangles from a sorted sequence

Tags: algorithm, triangle-count

Given a strictly increasing sequence of `n` positive integers `A(1) < A(2) < ... < A(n)`. We need to find the number of triangles with side lengths as `3` distinct elements of this sequence.

Since `n <= 6000`, checking every possible combination is not fast enough. Is there any better algorithm? Thanks for any help.

My pseudocode:

```
for i from 0 till n - 2
    for j from i+1 till n-1
        for k from j+1 till n
            if A[i] + A[j] > A[k] then count += 1
            else break
```

Comment: What is your actual algorithm? Can you give us an example?

Comment: I've added my psuedo-code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can exclude the third cycle and look for max k value with binary search. Complexity is O(N^2*Log(N)
2. You can reach better time - O(N^2) - just think how to use monotonicity property.